# adding quotes around shellscript parameter from Jenkins/groovy

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, kubernetes-helm

I'm building a pipeline in Jenkins, and in this pipeline, I call a shellscript: `sh "helm upgrade --install $app --set myVar=$myVar"`

now, after trying this in the terminal on my local machine, I've discovered that for some values of `myVar`, it needs to be quoted on the commandline. (specifically I'm passing a YAML list, example: `"{foo,bar,baz}"` )

Now it turns out this is not as simple as it would seem. my first attempt was:

```
sh "helm upgrade --install $app --set myVar='$myVar'"
```

but in the logs, we see that the command that was ultimately ran looks like

```
sh helm upgrade --install appname --set myvar={foo,bar,baz}
```

and this, frustratingly, doesn't get parsed the right way by helm.

so I think to myself, "double quotes would work too", and I try:

```
sh "helm upgrade --install appname --set myvar=\"$myVar\""
```

but alas, the logs tell that same old story:

```
sh helm upgrade --install appname --set myvar={foo,bar,baz}
```

so. How do i convince my jenkins-pipeline to run the command as

```
sh "helm upgrade --install appname --set myvar="{foo,bar,baz}"
```

and also, why doesn't this work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into similar issue some time ago and the solution to this problem is quite simple, yet pretty counter intuitive. You have to escape double quote with triple backslash. Take a look at this very simple example:

```groovy
node {
    stage('Test') {
        sh "echo \\\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\\""
    }
}
```

And this is the console output:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
+ echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: This is the solution. The "triple backslash" is actually ` \\ ` (escaped backslash) and `\"` (escaped double-quote) - The `sh` build step performs its own parameter expansion before shelling out, meaning that the the escaped quote is consumed by the process of building the command that will be passed to the shell. To pass the literal `"` through to the actual bash shell command, you need to escape _both_ the backslash and the double-quote.

Comment: oh, the old "escape it more" technique! why didn't I think of that? Ill give it a go and report back shortly, thanks!