# Jenkins Pipeline script to escape hyphen or print quotes

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, escaping, jenkins-pipeline

I want to execute the following maven command from the pipeline script but the hyphen or quotes is not working

```
pipeline {
agent { 
    label 'master' 
  }
  environment {
    Blah
    Blah..
  } 
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh "echo 'Build_Id:  ' $BUILD_ID"
            sh "echo 'Job_Name:  '  $JOB_NAME"
            sh "echo 'Build_Name:  '  $BUILD_NAME"
            sh "echo 'Current Branch Name:  '  $BRANCH"
            sh 'mvn clean package deploy -DskipTests -pl "AML-BI"'
          }
       }
   }
}
post {
  success {
    }
  failure {
    }
   always{
    }
  }
}
```

I tried single quotes, double quotes, backslashes escaping and concatenation but nothing's working

```
[Pipeline] sh
[Business-Information-UK AML-BI] Running shell script
+ mvn clean package deploy -P buildserver02,!artifactory -DskipTests -pl AML-BI
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: AML-BI @ 
[ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor: AML-BI -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Ther is a module "AML-BI" in the project and I want the script to be executed as

```
mvn clean package deploy -P buildserver02,!artifactory -DskipTests -pl "AML-BI"
```

Comment: Your call of maven duplicates many things. Just use `mvn clean deploy ..` nothing else using `mvn clean package deploy` will run several parts of the life cycle duplicate...is `AML-BI` an artifactId of the module?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/a/50974018/4121744 is what you're after (when it doubt, add more escape chars!)

Comment: @khmarbaise, thank you for telling me of the duplication, learnt a thing and yes "AML-BI" is the artifactId of the module, cheers

Comment: Thank you @bto, changed my script to sh "mvn clean deploy -P buildserver02,!artifactory -DskipTests -pl \\\"AML-BI\\\"" and it's working now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like me, if you're looking for the solution, changing the script line to:

```
sh "mvn clean deploy -P buildserver02,!artifactory -DskipTests -pl \\\"AML-BI\\\""
```

did the trick and is working now. Thanks for the comments!

Here is the snippet from the log:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[Some-Project-Information AML-BI] Running shell script
+ mvn clean deploy -P buildserver02,!artifactory -DskipTests -pl "AML-BI"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AML-BI
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://somebuildseriver/artifactory/libs-snapshot//0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
776/776 B   

Downloaded: http://somebuildseriver/artifactory/libs-snapshot//0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (776 B at 3.8 KB/sec)
[INFO]
....
```